# variable dynamic span overlap

Tags: php, html

```
$lines = file("res_example.txt");

$resArr = array();
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
  $columns = explode("\t", $line);
  $raws = $columns['1'];
  $hits = $columns['2'];
  $names = $columns['0'];
  $models = $columns['3'];
  $colors = $columns['4'];
  $allModels[$models] = 1;
  $resArr[] = array(
    name => $names,
    score => $raws,
    hit => $hits,
    model => $models,
    color => $colors
  );
}


$seqArr = array('A', 'T', 'C', 'G');
$randseq = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
  $randseq[] = $seqArr[array_rand($seqArr)];
}

$res = "";

echo "<div id=\"coltext\" style=\"font-family:monospace;\">";

foreach ($allModels as $modName => $value) {

  echo "<input ModelName=$modName type=\"checkbox\"
  checked==\"TRUE\" onclick=\"toggle.apply(this)\" />$modName";

}

echo "<hr />";
$score = rawtransform($raw);
foreach ($randseq as $index => $nuc) {
  $index = $index + 1;
  foreach ($resArr as $hitArr) {
    $hit = $hitArr['hit'];
    $raw = $hitArr['score'];
    $model = $hitArr['model'];
    $colval = $hitArr['color'];
    $score = rawtransform($raw);

    $color = getcolor($score, $colval);

    if (($hit+3) == $index) { 
      echo "</span>";
    }
    if ($hit == $index) { 
      echo "<span class=$model Title=\"position:$index,score:$raw\"
      style=\"background:$color;\" color=\"$color\">";
      //problem when theres overlap !? 
    }

  }

  echo $nuc;

  if (($index%50)==0){
    echo"<br />";
  }
}

echo "</div>";

function rawtransform($raw) {
  return (int)($raw/50)-9;
}

function getcolor($score,$ArrayModelval)
{
switch ($score){
// working.  test each color. 
case 1: /*500-550(Raw Score)*/
        $col=$ArrayModelval;
            return"hsl( $col,100%,90%)";
    break;
case 2: //550-600
        $col=$ArrayModelval;
            return "hsl( $col,100%,85%)";
    break;
case 3: //600-650
        $col=$ArrayModelval;
            return "hsl( $col,100%,85%)";
    break;
case 4: //650-700
        $col=$ArrayModelval;
            return"hsl( $col,100%,80%)";
    break;
case 5: //700-750
        $col=$ArrayModelval;
            return"hsl( $col,100%,70%)";
    break;
case 6: //750-800
        $col=$ArrayModelval;
            return "hsl( $col,100%,60%)";
    break;
case 7: //800-850
        $col=$ArrayModelval;
            return "hsl( $col,100%,50%)";
    break;
case 8: //850-900;
        $col=$ArrayModelval;
            return "hsl( $col,100%,50%)";
    break;
case 9: //900-950
        $col=$ArrayModelval;
            return "hsl( $col,100%,40%)";
    break;
case 10: //950-1000
        $col=$ArrayModelval;
    return "hsl($col,100%,40%)";
    break;

   }
}
```

For the most part does what I want: I want to color parts of the random seqeunce where there is a `$hit` - defined on external file.  My only problem is when there is any overlap, i.e. if two hits are within 3 bases of each other the span is elongated and colored as if its one span.

The external file has a position to start a span which have variable colors depending on a score given in the external file.  Basically if I have 3 results, 2 of which have almost the same hit (+-1) and the other a different hit, I would only see two sections colored, can anyone see what my problem is? Sorry I know I probably worded this horribly but its hard to explain. Thanks.

```
>chr1:2198584545754_genome_1000+    500 1000    Model1  0
>chr2:2198581212154_genome_1000+    510 992     Model2  180
>chr3:2115151215754_genome_1000+    520 990     Model3  330  
>chr4:2198584545754_genome_1000+    530 980     Model3  330 
>chr5:1218455145754_genome_1000+    540 970     Model2  180
>chr6:1231354645454_genome_1000+    550 960     Model1  0
>chr7:1231213211134_genome_1000+    600 950     Model3  330
>chr7:1231213211134_genome_1000+    650 940     Model3  330
```

javascript:

```
function toggle() {
var div= document.getElementById('coltext');
var modName=this.getAttribute('ModelName');
var spans=div.getElementsByTagName('span');
var spans_l=spans.length;
while (spans_l--){
    span=spans[spans_l];
    if(span.getAttribute('class')==modName && this.checked==true){
        var color= span.getAttribute('color');

        span.style.background=color;
    }
    if(span.getAttribute('class')==modName && this.checked==false){
        span.style.background="white";
    }
}

}
```

Comment: *Please* indent your code sensibly and consistently, it makes it much harder to debug when you don't. Please also show example input data and the desired output.

Comment: Also you should use the [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function for reading data from the file, and you are creating a load of unnecessary variables within the `foreach` - you could just do `$resArr[] = array('name' => $columns['0'], 'score' => $columns['1'], 'hit' => $columns['2'], 'model' => $columns['3'], 'color' => $columns['4']);`

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice appreciate the help.

Comment: Also, if you could, can you explain why i should use fgetcsv? so i know for further use. thanks

Comment: Mostly in this case because it will be much more memory efficient. The `file()` call reads the whole file into memory, then you iterate over it and create a new array that holds essentially the same data, so you basically have two copies of the file in memory. By opening a file pointer and reading one line at a time, you have a maximum of one copy of the file + 1 line in memory at any one time. It also combines the two operations - reading the file and creating a parsed array - into one, which will be a bit faster.

Comment: Can you also provide the output you are getting at the moment and the output you would like instead?

Comment: Thanks thats very helpful.... I dont now how to show it from this physically as it doesnt include my coloring.  However the problem is : Normally span will open if a hit = index.  if index= hit +3 closes that span.  However when there are two hits within close proximity e.g. hit1=90,hit2=92, the second span opens where the first one should end,

Comment: What would you do instead? How would you overlay the colors? Are all your colors expressed as 24-bit hex (`#ACBDEF`)?

Comment: my colors are in hsl.  I have a function which will return an appropriate hsl statment when given a score as a parameter. This hsl statment is inserted into my code above aas $color...I can't think of a way out of this yet,im thinking i need to change the way i insert span tags in my code

Comment: `im thinking i need to change the way i insert span tags` - That is true, but the more salient point is what would you do with the colors when two hits overlap? Say for example I had a hit that started at 90 colored red, and another that started at 92 colored blue. 90 and 91 will be red, 94 and 95 will be blue, but what color would the characters at 92 and 93 be? I personally would imagine you'd want to color them purple (half way between red and blue) but what would you do?

Comment: i initially wanted to split the colors horizontally across the text, so top half is one color bottom half another, hwoever this would be way out of my capabilites at the moment. So i also though a mixture of the colors, or even a seperate color for hits that overlap all together.

Comment: `initially wanted to split the colors horizontally across the text, so top half is one color bottom half another.` A cross-browser implementation of this would be nearly impossible, I would imagine. I half re-wrote your script last night, give me an hour to wake up properly and I will will finish it off and post as an answer :-)

Comment: yes it was a niave thought, and that became apparent very quickly. thank you very very much thats fantastic, thank you so much:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size. It works by using a FIFO stack `$currentHits` to handle the hit boundaries. I have also added a few helper functions to deal with color generation - if you alter your `getcolor()` function to return an array instead of a CSS string one of them could be dropped, making it more efficient.

<strike>I have been unable to test this because I don't have the source code for your `getcolor()` or `rawtransform()` functions - if you add these to the question I am certain further improvements can be made and I can test the code properly.</strike> Also, it would be good to see what your CSS `Model1`, `Model2` etc classes look like.

*Edit: now includes* `getcolor()`*/*`rawtransform()` *functions and (at least partially) [tested](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GQnHLi)*

```
<?php

  function rawtransform ($raw) {
    return (int) ($raw / 50) - 9;
  }
  function getcolor ($score, $h) {
    switch ($score) {
      // working.  test each color. 
      case 1: /*500-550(Raw Score)*/
        $l = 90;
        break;
      case 2: case 3: //550-650
        $l = 85;
        break;
      case 4: //650-700
        $l = 80;
        break;
      case 5: //700-750
        $l = 70;
        break;
      case 6: //750-800
        $l = 60;
        break;
      case 7: case 8: //800-900;
        $l = 50;
        break;
      case 9: case 10: default: //900-1000 / out of range
        $l = 40;
        break;
    }
    return array(
      'h' => $h,
      's' => 100,
      'l' => $l
    );
  }

  function hsl_average_color () {
    // Takes an unlimited number of arguments, calculates the average HSL value and returns a CSS string
    $args = func_get_args();
    $h = $s = $l = array();
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
      $h[] = $arg['h'];
      $s[] = $arg['s'];
      $l[] = $arg['l'];
    }
    return sprintf('hsl(%d, %d%%, %d%%)', (int) round(array_sum($h) / count($h)), (int) round(array_sum($s) / count($s)), round(array_sum($l) / count($l)));
  }

  $fileName = 'res_example.txt';

  // Open the file
  if (!$fp = fopen($fileName, 'r')) {
    // Handle file read errors here
    die("Unable to open file $fileName");
  }

  // Loop the file data and build an associative array
  $resArr = array();
  while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {

    // You didn't declare $allModels as an empty array before the loop
    // Should you have?
    $allModels[$line[3]] = 1;

    // Note that I have dropped the hit key and instead keyed the outer
    // array by this value. I have added an end key to track the end of
    // a hit
    $resArr[$line[2]] = array(
      'name' => $line[0],
      'score' => $line[1],
      'end' => $line[2] + 4,
      'model' => $line[3],
      'color' => getcolor(rawtransform($line[1]), $line[4])
    );

  }

  // Close the file
  fclose($fp);

  // Generate a random sequence
  $seqArr = array('A', 'T', 'C', 'G');
  $randseq = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $randseq[] = $seqArr[array_rand($seqArr)];
  }

  // $res appears to do nothing in you code
  // $res = "";

  // Open the <div>
  echo '<div id="coltext" style="font-family:monospace;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;">'."\n";

  // Iterate over $allModels and echo checkboxes
  foreach ($allModels as $modName => $value) {

    // ModelName is a non-standard HTML attribute, are you sure you meant to do this?
    echo '<input ModelName="'.$modName.'" type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="toggle.apply(this);" />'.$modName."\n";

  }

  echo "<hr />\n";

  // This line does nothing useful here
  // $score = rawtransform($raw);

  // An array to track the current hits
  $currentHits = array();

  foreach ($randseq as $index => $nuc) {

    // Increment $index
    $index++;

    // Track whether we are in a hit/reached a boundary
    $boundary = FALSE;
    $inHit = (bool) count($currentHits);

    // Check whether we are at the end of the lowest hit in the stack
    if ($inHit && $index == $currentHits[0]['end']) {
      $boundary = TRUE;
      array_shift($currentHits);    
    }

    // Check whether we are at the start of a new hit
    if (isset($resArr[$index])) {
      $boundary = TRUE;
      $currentHits[] = $resArr[$index];    
    }

    // If we reached a boundary
    if ($boundary) {

      // Close a hit    
      if ($inHit) {
        echo "</span>";
      }

      // Open a hit
      if (count($currentHits)) {

        // Get the current color value
        $colors = array();
        foreach ($currentHits as $hit) $colors[] = $hit['color'];
        $color = call_user_func_array('hsl_average_color', $colors);

        // Start a new span
        echo '<span class="'.$currentHits[0]['model'].'" title="position:'.$index.',score:'.$currentHits[0]['score'].'" style="color: '.$color.';">';

      }

    }

    // Print the character
    echo $nuc;

    // Split into 50 character chunks        
    if (!($index % 50)){
      echo"<br />\n";
    }

  }

  // Close the last span if one is still open
  if (count($currentHits)) {
    echo "</span>";
  }

  // Close the <div>        
  echo "</div>\n";
```

Comment: Thanks so much , ill have a look at this now, ive edited my q to show my functions.  Thanks very much

Comment: I cannot get this working with my code:/ .. Im confused about the hsl functions and how they impliment color?

Comment: Also: is `pre_match` intended to be pre_match? .. Ive never heard of pre_match, ive heard of preg_match but never utilised it, so unsure.

Comment: @user1338194 See edited code above. That should have been `preg_match()` but I have now removed the need for it by modifying `getcolor()`

Comment: Thank you very much, i have learned a huge amount from this code, i had never heard of some of the functions, I really appreciate it.  just another thing if you have time.  I tested this with multiple overlaps and only some of them work ? even though the results file is consistent ? in one case it does the same as before , in another case it doesn do anything with the second hit in an overplap, e.e. p:990 , P:992 - only p:900 shown ?

Comment: Forget that problem, it was a problem with the results file.  I cannot express my grattitude to you for this , thank you, a bit of relief for the weekend now :)

Comment: No worries :-D I suppose the key idea to take away from this is the use of a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(data_structure)) (also sometimes referred to as a [FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))) to track the boundaries between hits. The logic behind color averaging function was thrown together quickly and is possibly a little flawed and may need more work, but representing the components of the colors as an array will certainly make it easier to calculate in-between colors dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, very much the FIFO is a great concept here. i had never heard of before.  Just have to get my javascript toggle function to work with this and this part almost done.  Thank you once again

Comment: one more quick thing i f you have time.  My toggle function will toggle the colors off, however will not put them back on, would it because of the use of array_shift? .. my javascript basically says if checkbox is checked and modelname of checkbox =modelname of hit, color, if not , put the background to white.  Any ideas? .. sorry if im bugging you now.

Comment: OK I see what you're doing with those classes now. Right well that *does* make it more interesting... So these colors should be applied as background colors for the spans, rather than text colors? It does make it much more difficult because of the overlaps and the fact that inline styles override class styles - I'll have to have a think about this one...

Comment: yes , however it it simplifies it text color could be ok, if it worked with my toggle?  Thanks for your time

Comment: Not really any simpler, it's just about the merged colors that makes it complicated whatever you apply them to. Are you using pure JS, jQuery or something else to do this? Can you add your existing JS to the question?

Comment: thats what i thought, Yes im using JS, ..no problem

Comment: Is the list of possible value for `Model*` finite? Will it always be `Model1`, `Model2`, `Model3` or is it an fluid list in the real world?

Comment: @user1338194 Right. The JS in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaveRandom/ynYqr/) works well with the output of [this PHP](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fp5SFq). In order to get this to work in a satisfactory way, I have had to offload some of the processing (like most of the color generation code) to the client side and just blindly pass some data to Javascript, but I'm actually quite pleased with the results. Only disadvantage is it requires JS in order for it to work. See if it meets your needs...

Comment: sorry i was away for the last few days.   this seems to do exctly what i want, and seems like a huge amount of work you have done to help me , so thanks so much , ill integrate this into my code and see how it goes.  Really , thank you very very very much for all your help.

Comment: No worries :-) Just make sure you understand exactly how it all works, to be sure that you can adapt it as your needs change. Feel free to come back and ask questions about anything you don't understand. There is one gaping hole in it, and that is the fact that there is an `eval()` in there, which always feels very wrong. You could get rid of this by using true JSON and a JSON parser - but the reason I did not do this is that JSON uses double quotes, which would need escaping to be passed in HTML attributes like that, which vastly increases the size of the output.

Comment: thanks, I haven't used javascript a whole lot.  Can you explain in english how it works all together, theres a lot going on. I see the coloring seems to be the same idea by on JS.  However, is it getting the hsl values from within the span tags i.e. $color? Also what is bad about eval, ive seen this before but never any warning about it?What is the constructor doing ? thanks for your help